# Mostrar informacion FireBase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Buenas, tengo una APP donde guardo Informacion sobre un Aviso en FireBase, a la hora de guardarlo lo tengo ya mas o menos bien y me guarda sobre cada usuario los avisos que envio.

Ahora necesito mostrar toda esa Informacion en otra pantalla distinta, he intentado hacerlo con un ListView pero no hace nada, alguna idea de donde puede estar el error? O alguna forma para hacerlo mejor?

```
public class VerAviso extends MenuAvisos
{

    List<Aviso> avisos;
    ListView list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.veraviso);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        final ArrayAdapter<Aviso> adapter;

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Aviso>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        database.getReference("Aviso").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                avisos.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot :
                        dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Aviso aviso2 = snapshot.getValue(Aviso.class);
                    avisos.add(aviso2);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Por si hace falta, el metodo el cual uso para guardar los Datos es este.

```
    private void saveInformation()
    {
        //getting current user
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        Aviso avisos = new Aviso();
        //Getting values from database
        avisos.setAviso(aviso1.getText().toString());
        avisos.setDescripcion(textDes.getText().toString());
        avisos.setUbicacion(textubi.getText().toString());

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Aviso").child(user.getUid());
        Aviso aviso2 = new Aviso(avisos.getAviso(),avisos.getDescripcion(),avisos.getUbicacion());
        myRef.push().setValue(aviso2);

        //displaying a success toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Guardando informacion del aviso, espera...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Ya estoy aqui, dime un ejemplo de que datos hay en aviso,descripcion y ubicacion, por favor. ¿Quieres mostrarlos en forma de lista en una nueva pagina como si de una lista de mensajes se tratara?

Comment: "Ahora necesito mostrar toda esa Información en otra pantalla distinta" ??? comentas que en un ListView pero cual es el problema en realidad?

Comment: El error que tienes es el que te publiqué en la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas pasar tu lista de objetos al [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) en su constructor:

Pero antes declara la `lista`:

```
avisos = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Aviso>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, avisos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma es utilizando RecyclerView

Para hacerlo con RecyclerView necesitas primero hacer 2 xml 
1 con El recyclerview
el otro con el xml de lo que tendra cada fila

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvAvisos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Filas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAviso"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AVISO"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescripcion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Descripción"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvUbicacion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ubicacion"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Despues necesitas un Adaptador , el cual recibira la lista de objetos y se encargara de que segun el tamaño de la lista de objetos, pase objeto por objeto poniendo la informacion en cada fila.

```
public class AdaptadorAvisos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorAvisos.AvisosviewHolder> {
List<Aviso> avisos;



public AdaptadorAvisos(List<Aviso> avisos) {
    this.avisos = avisos;


}

@Override
public AvisosviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_avisos, parent, false);
    AvisosviewHolder holder = new AvisosviewHolder(v);


    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AvisosviewHolder holder, int position) {
    Aviso aviso = avisos.get(position);
    holder.tvAviso.setText(aviso.get(position).getAvisos);
    holder.tvDescripcion.setText(aviso.get(position).getDescripcion);
    holder.tvUbicacion.setText(aviso.get(position).getUbicacion);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return  avisos.size();
}

public static class AvisosviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {


    TextView tvAviso;
    TextView tvDescripcion;
    TextView tvUbicacion;



    public AvisosviewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvAviso = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAviso);
        tvDescripcion = (TextView ) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
        tvUbicacion = (TextView ) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUbicacion);


    }


}
```

}

Por ultimo el Main donde llenas la lista de objetos y mandas la lista al adapter y el adapter lo mandas al RecyclerView

```
    public class VerAviso extends AppCompatActivity
{
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    List<Aviso> avisos;
    RecyclerView rv;
    Adapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_avisos);

        avisos = new ArrayList<>();

        rv=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvAvisos);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new Adapter(avisos);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        database.getReference("Aviso").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                avisos.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot :
                        dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Aviso aviso2 = snapshot.getValue(Aviso.class);
                    avisos.add(aviso2);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Y listo , asi trabajaras con los datos la proxima vez.

Comment: Es mejor el RecyclerView que el ListView? por cambiarlo y que sea mejor

Comment: @CristianPrietoBeltran Depende del uso que tengas planeado, ListView es como la manera light y RecyclerView es la manera ¿avanzada? por asi decir, siendo un control de manejo de datos de lista mas flexible permitiendo seguir un modelo , ademas se mantiene como una sola tarea como lo dice su propio nombre, reciclando los objetos. En lo personal prefiero el RecyclerView. Prueba el codigo y veras.

Comment: En otro proyecto ya tengo implementado un RecyclerView asi que mas o menos se como funciona y me gusto bastante, asi que implementare en esta par ver como queda mejor de las 2. Gracias!

Comment: @CristianPrietoBeltran Alli me cuentas.

Comment: Donde pone adapter = new Adapter(eventos), eventos a que se referia? Que me da un null pointer i creo que es que he puesto (usuarios)

Comment: @CristianPrietoBeltran Olvide cambiar eso, es tu lista avisos